# 99 bottles of beer in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

The following code and query doesn't work:

```
bottles(X) :-
    write(X), write(' bottles of beer on the wall,'), nl,
    write(X), write(' bottles of beer,'), nl,
    write('Take one down, and pass it around,'), nl,
    X1 is X - 1,
    write(X1), write(' bottles of beer on the wall.'), nl,
    bottles(X1).
bottles(1) :-
    write('1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer,'), nl,
    write('Take one down, and pass it around,'), nl,
    write('Now they are alle gone.'), nl.

?- bottles(99).
```

With SWI-Prolog 8.3.15 on Windows I can even not press Ctrl-C.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: The Ctrl-C problem could be related to https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/debugger-interrupts/3339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will always keep recursing since the first rule never says that `X` should be greater than one. You thus fix this with:

```
bottles(X) :-
    X > 1,  %% ← check that X is greater than one.
    write(X), write(' bottles of beer on the wall,'), nl,
    write(X), write(' bottles of beer,'), nl,
    write('Take one down, and pass it around,'), nl,
    X1 is X - 1,
    write(X1), write(' bottles of beer on the wall.'), nl,
    bottles(X1).
bottles(1) :-
    write('1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer,'), nl,
    write('Take one down, and pass it around,'), nl,
    write('Now they are alle gone.'), nl.
```

Comment: This was a test. Somebody close voted my question about cut elimination in Prolog. So I deleted it before it gets closed. But 99 bottles is ok for stackoverflow. Very interesting...

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse: well I had nothing to do with that. I think this *is* on-topic. The only reason I can think of is that people might see this more as the *theory of logic programming*, and thus might belong to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Not really. Its just a programming exercise. Instead of programming 99 bottles, you code cut elimination, which is a proof transformation. Prolog is very suitable for proof transformations. Its not the Prolog cut (!).

Comment: Its basically there are 99 cuts, you take one cut down, there are 98 cuts, etc.. Just joking, but this isn't even wrong.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse: why would you delete the question before it really got closed ?

Comment: @gusbro Because usually a close vote animates others to also close vote. So sooner or later the question would be closed, making the question unusable.